# Nearly proficient, is that good?

Tags: education

Our first grader got his progress report. He is a great kid, and we take no issue with his progress report, but we are still wondering about the meaning of "nearly proficient" on some of the items. (For what it's worth, both parents are ESL and not familiar with the terminology.)

Does it mean a continuous below-desired performance on these items, like "averaging a 5 out of 10" (which is also *just* below a "pass")? This would probably mean having to catch up on these items.

Or does it mean they have to achieve a grade proficiency for the year, and at this halfway mark through the year, they already nearly achieved that? This would probably mean cruising comfortably to the finish line.

Thanks.

Edit: Beaverton School District in Oregon, USA

Comment: I assume this is United States in my answer, based on your language - it would be helpful to clarify the country, and if possible the state, as this will depend some (but mostly just on country).

Comment: Yeah, silly for me to not include those details. I did so now, we're in the United States indeed.

Comment: That's great information - I found the explainer for your school district and added a link and some information at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 6):

TL;DR - the second of your explanations, mostly (it is a "point in time" evaluation, and not the final score the child will receive, most likely) - but it depends.  This answer assumes United States based on the specific language used in the question, and will likely not apply to other countries' educational systems.

---

The Common Core, in the United States, has standardized the concept of skills-based grading, often using the term "proficiency" to indicate whether a student has met that standard.  The other important change to many schools is a move towards grading that indicates whether a student is on track to meet standards, a "point in time" measurement, rather than a reflection of the student's work in and of itself over that time (as most of current adults are used to from our childhood).

Some skills are relatively short, and typically taught in a few days or weeks, within one grading period; but particularly at the first grade level, the entire year covers teaching only a relatively few skills (as the skills are fairly high level at that grade) and so a student in the first trimester or quarter might be *expected* only to reach part of the standard.

For example, if your student were in California, the [California Core Standards for Mathematics](https://www.cde.ca.gov/be/st/ss/documents/ccssmathstandardaug2013.pdf) include the following:

> Represent and solve problems involving addition and subtraction.
>
> > 1. Use addition and subtraction within 20 to solve word problems involving situations of adding to, taking from, putting together, taking apart, and comparing, with unknowns in all positions, e.g., by using objects, drawings, and equations with a symbol for the unknown number to represent the problem.
> > 2. Solve word problems that call for addition of three whole numbers whose sum is less than or equal to 20, e.g., by using objects, drawings, and equations with a symbol for the unknown number to represent the problem.

This concept is likely introduced in the first trimester, and some students might start out proficient in it - students with academically focused preschools, for example, likely will.  But most students will not know how to add going into first grade, and so will spend much of the year working on this skill.  It will be introduced perhaps in the first trimester, and then, depending on the curriculum used, it might be practiced for the entire year - for example, with Eureka (the curriculum used at my local school), they have "sprints", which are long lists of short, related problems (think, "5+4", "5+9", "5+2",  etc., all ten 5+ facts repeated about 30 total on a page), that both serve as a way for the teacher to gauge how a student can add, and reinforce the addition facts.

In order to show parents how their students are doing on these skills, report cards will generally show a student is either "proficient" in a skill (meaning they have mastered that skill), "nearly proficient/approaching proficiency" (meaning the student is not yet proficient at the skill, but has mastered some elements), "minimally proficient" (does not yet have significant mastery of the skill), or usually something that indicates the student shows no evidence of proficiency (wording varies a lot on that level).  (Some schools also have a higher rating than Proficient, but as that's not really a standard, it's less easy to define.)

It is hard to tell whether a "nearly proficient" is a good score or not, particularly in first grade.  However, for the *most* part, in February it is not unexpected for many of the skills to be "nearly proficient" rather than "proficient".  My children both receive "nearly proficient" marks on most of their pre-may report cards in various skills, and even some "minimally proficient", but both typically progress to "proficient" in all skills by the final trimester.  The best thing to do is to use this report card in the teacher conversations - hopefully you have a meeting with the teacher about as often as report cards come out, most schools do this by design - and have the teacher point out which skills you can work on.  Nearly all skills will continue to be developed over the year in the first grade, but this is really important for the teacher to explain as it will depend on the skill, the teacher, and the curriculum.

Your school should have a "report card explainer" that will go in more detail about what the specific meanings are for the specific standard terminology, such as [this one](https://www.ddouglas.k12.or.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Parent-Guide-to-Elementary-Proficiency-Based-Report-Card.pdf); it may not match that specifically (this was just randomly picked from a search, but there are many - pick the one for your school district).  This usually is sent out with report cards. If this was't sent out, ask!

If you want to learn more about the standards, you can read the standards for your state (these are mostly state level). For example, for California the math standards are [here](https://www.cde.ca.gov/be/st/ss/documents/ccssmathstandardaug2013.pdf) and  the "English" (meaning reading/writing for the most part) standards are [here](https://www.cde.ca.gov/ci/rl/cf/elaeldfrmwrksbeadopted.asp).  Each state's standards will be a bit different; however, they will likely be based in part on the [Common Core standards](http://www.corestandards.org).  There are some good "explainers" that can help you understand what kinds of things your student may be expected to learn as part of these skills; for example, these [parent roadmaps](https://www.cgcs.org/domain/149) are grade specific explanations of what is being taught and include example problems.

---

Additionally, your school district has an explanation under its [Standards Based Learning page](https://www.beaverton.k12.or.us/departments/curriculum-instruction-assessment/standards-based-learning), which explains:

> The terms "Scoring Guide" and "Rubric" can be used interchangeably.  A Scoring Guide / Rubric is a document that describes student performance around a particular skill or area of knowledge.  The descriptions within a scoring guide should not only differentiate the levels of performance, it should clearly identify what success looks like.  An effective scoring guide, when used to evaluate student work, should answer three basic questions:
>
> Where am I going?
> Where am I now?
> What must I do to close the gap?
> Within Beaverton School District's Standards-Based Learning System, each Academic Learning Target has a rubric describing four levels of performance.
>
> > 4 -Highly Proficient
> >
> > 3 - Proficient
> >
> > 2 - Nearly Proficient
> >
> > 1 - Developing

Comment: Wonderful answer: helpful, factual, reassuring. While I had to know PA's core standards (I homeschooled my kids), I didn't officially give final grades to my kids (we had to have a certified teacher do this, so I didn't know this grading system. TIL.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, a great answer from @nick012000 -- "**Ask the teacher**" -- was deleted.

Where I live, there are some standard dates in the school year when parent-teacher conferences take place.  However, one can request a conference at any time.

I found that I was able to get more out of my conferences if I was able to review ahead of time at least some of the materials the teacher was going to show me in the conference.  That way I was able to use the limited conference time (e.g. 20 minutes) for questions.

Here are some preparation steps that helped me get the most out of my conferences:

- Emailing the teacher and asking them to send home, or attach to an email, photocopies of any work samples that will be shared during the conference.
- Asking for my child's results in any **assessments** or **benchmarks** that might have been done this school year (e.g. Developmental Reading Assessment or DRA) -- or a preview of what will be done.  (The terms in bold are part of elementary school lingo.)
- Requesting a copy of a rubric or handout that will help you get the most out of reading the progress report.
- Jotting down some questions to take along, with the top priority questions at the top.  For example:  *What is my child's learning style?  What are his/her strengths?  Challenges?  (Both academically and socially.)  What do you, as a teacher, enjoy most about having my child in your classroom?  How do I get access to the Parent Portal?  Will cursive and/or touch-typing be taught at this school?  In what grades?*  And any specific questions that occur to you after reviewing the materials that were hopefully shared with you ahead of time.

The conference is also a good time to share information, for example, what the child seems to enjoy the most about school, any challenges noticed at home, any recent or upcoming family changes, any exposure to other languages at home, etc.

Also note that projecting a relaxed, appreciative attitude, and bringing a donation of a 12-pack of Kleenex will help the teacher look forward to the next conference.

---

I did some reading.  OMG.

Apparently *proficiency-based grading* (I'll call this PBG to save some typing -- I just made that up) is the same as *standards-based grading*, and the basic idea seems to be that before this was introduced, you would get a letter grade or a number in each progress report of the year, and then there would be some averaging at the end of the year.  Whereas with PBG, each progress report is a snapshot in time, showing  sort of how full the glass is at that point in time. No averaging.

Some stuff I found:

[A study about PBG in Oregon](https://njctl-media.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/Effective%20grading%20practices%20in%20the%20middle%20school%20and%20high%20school%20environments.pdf). It's about secondary school (middle and high), but I found the critical student quotes about PBG illuminating.

A [blog post](https://www.teachthought.com/pedagogy/proficiency-based-grading/) with a positive overview of PBG (not specific to Oregon).

A [Beaverton middle school publication](https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1633730258/beavertonk12orus/yjsm4af2gifmtvvsf2fc/HPMShandbook.pdf) that explains the grading system, with examples.  Looks quite complicated.

A [letter to the editor](https://www.mailtribune.com/since-you-asked/2018/12/27/proficiency-grading-an-option-no-longer-required/) about grading systems in Oregon.  Not very recent, but interesting.

A Portland, OR, [teacher page](https://www.pps.net/Page/8009) describing PBG.  She says the goal of PBG is to provide "an accurate picture of a student’s progress in mastering the Oregon State Standards so that teachers can provide the specific supports or acceleration each student needs."  Also she says that it "communicates progress toward mastery of standards."

Something from Vermont, along the lines of what I was hoping to find for Beaverton or Oregon -- "[A Parent's Guide to PB Reporting](https://millriverschools.org/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/A-Parents-Guide-to-Proficiency-based-Reporting.pdf)."  Includes a nice Q&A.

A non-self-explanatory one-page [info sheet](https://resources.finalsite.net/images/v1639420105/beavertonk12orus/wskano3v5t8eaxzdhyyt/qrg_grade1_access_4.pdf) about assessments and benchmarks for 1st grade in 2021-22 in Beaverton.

I tried to find something about *how to read your child's progress report* at the Oregon education department and the Beaverton district, but struck out.  Maybe I didn't look hard enough.  Among other things, I looked at the [BSD STUDENT & FAMILY HANDBOOK](http://BSD%20STUDENT%20&%20FAMILY%20HANDBOOK) (confession: it was very long and I didn't read the whole thing), a [page](http://Resources%20for%20Parents/Guardians) of Apps and Resources for Parents/Guardians, and an [Assessment page](https://www.beaverton.k12.or.us/departments/curriculum-instruction-assessment/assessments).

Comment: We will of course ask the teacher, but this still seemed like a good question in the interim.

Comment: @SanderVerhagen - Indeed.  I do find it funny that there wasn't an accompanying sheet explaining the phrases used.